# How to use defines in other files?

Tags: variable

I can properly use a define

```
\def <command> <parameter-text>{<replacement-text>}
```

if it is define in the same LaTeX file, which is not the main file, but let's say, it is named `2.intro.tex` which is included with `\input{section/2.intro}`.

However, if I put the define in the `main.tex` of even in another file which in included before `2.intro`, it does not work. When compiling, it says
`! Undefined control sequence.`

Any help on how to solve this problem?

---

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{elsarticle}                                      

\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                

\begin{document}                                                                   

\begin{frontmatter}                                                                
\def\mylabel{[My Label in Main2]}                                                  
\lipsum[1]                                                                         
\end{frontmatter}                                                                  
\input{intro}                                                                      

\end{document}
```

---

#### `intro.tex`

```
\lipsum[1]                                                                         

Trying to use \mylabel
```

Comment: `\input` has no effect on the scope of commands, tex works just as if the contents of the file were copied at that place, so if you get undefined commands the error will be elsewhere. post a small example that shows the problem.

Comment: I guess I the problem is having anything defined between `begin` and `end`, I just realized that now.

Comment: Indeed `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` generally comes with an implicit group so that definitions inside the environment stay local to that environment unless they are explicitly made `\global`.

Comment: it should be `\newcommand` not `\def` and before the `\begin{frontmatter}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to `\input` you would see the same from

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{elsarticle}                                      

\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                

\begin{document}                                                                   

\begin{frontmatter}                                                                
\def\mylabel{[My Label in Main2]}                                                  
\lipsum[1]                                                                         
\end{frontmatter}                                                                  
\mylabel                                                               

\end{document}
```

You want the definition outside the group so

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{elsarticle}                                      

\usepackage{lipsum}                                                                

\begin{document}                                                                   

\newcommand\mylabel{[My Label in Main2]}                                                  
\begin{frontmatter}                                                                

\lipsum[1]                                                                         
\end{frontmatter}                                                                  
\mylabel                                                                    

\end{document}
```